# Ajax call in android app

Tags: android, ajax

I am trying to make a cross domain request in my android application which returns a jsonp.

```
$('#loader-message').text("Please wait while we retrieve the inventory status");
$.ajax({
       type:'GET',
       url: 'myUrl',
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       success: function( data ) {
         console.log(data);
       },
       error: function( data ) {
         console.log("error");
       }
     });
```

Now when I run this in my browser it works fine.

The problem is in my emulator/actual app, it just shows me the loading message as above **"Please wait while we retrieve the inventory status"**

Now my question is **"Is the ajax call being made at least ?"**
Also if not then how do I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my above issue by using ionic-angular.

```
var exampleApp = angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])    
exampleApp.controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getData = function() {
          $http.get("myUrl", { params: { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" } })
            .success(function(data) {                
            })
            .error(function(data) {                
            });        
    }});
```